# Google Admin API with Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I currently have a script that takes an email address and role from a Google Spreadsheet and adds them to a Google Apps Admin Group, using the Google Admin SDK from [this website](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory).  However, I'm looking for a similar script that works to delete users from a list, coming from a spreadsheet.  There is an API from Google [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#delete_member), however, I'm not sure how to implement it from the spreadsheet with a Google Script.  How can I do this?  Any help is appreciated!

Here is what I have now for adding a user from a spreadsheet:

```
function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = getUser();
  var groupEmail = getGroup();
  var member = {
      email: userEmail,
      role: getRole()
   };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}

function getUser() {
  user = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue();
  return user }

function getRole() {
  role = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();
  return role }
```

Comment: Clarification, when you say 'Remove them from a list', do you mean remove them from cells in a spreadsheet, or do you mean remove the users from the group (essentially doing the reverse of your sample code?) StackOverflow is usually here to help with specific programming roadblocks, rather then write code for you, but I'll see if I can point you in the right direction depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the line `member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);`, use:

```
member = AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupKey, memberKey);
```

EDIT: bad copy/paste from my code. Documentation on this is [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/delete).

Comment: this is removing the user from the google platform not from a google group, and the API that was mentioned in the post was the API to "Delete membership in a group" not completely the user no?

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake. Forgot to edit the code for my example of this. That'll teach me to post so early in the morning :)

Answer (score 1):

try with this command line:

```
AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupKey, memberKey);
```

where groupeKey is the email adress of the group and memberKey is the email adress of the user